# How to insert/update element within a migration that has a many-to-one relationship

Tags: typescript, migration, nestjs, typeorm

I got a little problem with saving factice data within a migration.

Im generating a user like this :

```
export class UserMigration1645626140921 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
const dummy1 = await queryRunner.manager.save(
            queryRunner.manager.create<User>(User, {
                login: 'dummy1',
                status: 'online',
            }),
        );
    }
```

I have an entity `message` that has a relation with the `user` entity and I'd like to create factice message

```
@Entity('message')
export class Message {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column()
    public content: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (author: User) => author.message)
    public author: User;
}
```

My  message migration  located in another file:

```
        const user = await getConnection()
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select("user")
            .from(User, "user")
            .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
            .getOne()


        const message1 = await queryRunner.manager.save(
            queryRunner.manager.create<Message>(Message, {
                content: 'Hello World',
                author: user
            }),
        );
```

Then I checked into my postgres db, it seems that my message is created but it doesn't link it with my dummy1 element

Another thing I've tried:

According to the TypeORM documentation (https://typeorm.io/relational-query-builder), I could use .relation :

```
await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Message, "author")
    .of(1)
    .set(1);
```

But it gives me a duplicate error in my user table.